# itext5 sign image over context

Tags: java, pdf, itext, sign

When I sign a document and I use an image in the signature appearance, I get this result:

[image]

However, I want the result to be like this:

[image]

This is my code:

```
PdfSignatureAppearance appearance =  stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
appearance.setReason(info.getReason());
appearance.setLocation(info.getLocation());
appearance.setVisibleSignature(t.getRectangle(), 1, "SIGN");
appearance.setSignatureGraphic(image); 
appearance.setCertificationLevel(PdfSignatureAppearance.NOT_CERTIFIED); 
appearance.setRenderingMode(PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.GRAPHIC);
MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, signature,chain, null, null, null, 0, MakeSignature.CryptoStandard.CADES);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The visual representation of a digital signature in a PDF document is a *widget annotation*. A *widget annotation* is a specific type of annotation.

In PDF, you have the actual content of a page. This content is stored in a content stream. A page is defined in a page dictionary. There's a `/Contents` entry in this page dictionary that refers to one of more content streams. Together these content streams contain the syntax that describes the content of a page.

Annotations are not part of any of those streams. Annotations are referred to from the page dictionary using the `/Annots` entry. In your case, there is an `/Annots` entry that refers to a widget annotation with the appearance of your signature.

**All annotations are rendered on top of the actual page content.**

To make a long story short: you have a PDF with some page content and the appearance of an annotation is added on top of that page content. This is normal. This is *as described in ISO-32000-1*. You are now asking for a PDF viewer to render annotations *under* the page content. This is not possible according to the PDF specification.

The short answer to your question is: you are asking something that can't be done. The closest you'll get to a solution is to make the image transparent (but that's another question).

Answer (score 0):

While Bruno's answer is correct - there is no way to make the signature annotation appearance to *be* beneath the content -, in some cases you can make it *appear* to be.

#### Blend mode use

Bruno already mentioned that one approach might be *to make the image transparent*. Regular (alpha channel style) transparency has one major disadvantage, though: the original content or the image (probably both) will appear somewhat pale. But there is a related technique in PDF for puting foreground and backdrop together in a special way: blend modes.

In particular if your pdf content is mostly black and white, using the blend mode **Darken** or **Multiply** will create a result looking like the desired image.

#### Signature graphic in content

If your pdf has not been signed yet, you can actually add the signature image to the page background itself, e.g. using the `UnderContent` of the `PdfStamper`. (If the page has an opaque background, e.g. due to white filled  rectangle as background, this will become a bit more difficult but still manageable.)

#### Page content in signature appearance

Alternatively you can draw a copy of the page content over the image in the signature annotation appearance. This also works for previously signed PDFs but is also sensitive to opaque page contents.

Comment: yes.when i using the  `stamper.getUnderContent() `  , the image is over the context .but now,i need sign.Actually ,i don't now what to connect  `PdfSignatureAppearance ` and `PdfContentByte`

Comment: As Bruno has explained in his answer, pdf pages have their genuine content plus annotations which hover above. By adding to the `UnderContent` you add to the genuine page content. By adding to the `PdfSignatureAppearance`, you add to the signature annotation, i.e. something hovering above.